# What is the difference between importing a POJO and injecting an EJB?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, dependency-injection, ejb-3.0, java-ee-6

As I was attempting to create a Dynamic Web Project in eclipse I received some notifications in eclipse telling me that I had to not only reference the EJB in the build but import that EJB package in addition to the @EJB dependency injection I used.

Can anyone help me clarify why all three are needed and what exactly is going on.  The reason I ask is because to me importing the EJB package alone would be enough to put the EJB class in scope of the calling class, and this indicates that I do not yet have a clear understanding of what JEE6 is trying to achieve with annotations.

Edit: to clarify, this is a general question about EJB's. It's actually working I'm just curious as to why importing the bean is needed in addition to the dependency injection. It seems like they're both just different ways to reference an EJB class in another file (servlet or bean, etc) but I don't think that is true there has to be SOME specific reason that injection is done with importing of the package/class of the bean.

Thank you,

Comment: "why all three" - can you list those ?

Comment: please be more specific... provide screenshots, or ask whatever you don't understand... and also tell us what are you trying to do(achieve)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like as if you're misinterpreting the meaning of Java's `import` keyword. It does not include the source code of the class in the current class like as PHP's `include()`, CSS `@import`, JSP's `<jsp:include>` does, or something. It does not inject anything in the code.

The `import` is mandatory when you're using non-FQN classnames in the code, so that the compiler understoods what class exactly you're referencing. Imagine that you have a class named `FooService` in multiple different packages other than the current package; without the import or an explicit FQN, the compiler wouldn't know which one you're referring to and thus can't do any checks if the code is functionally fine (i.e. the class is been used and accessed the right way with the right field/method names and the right method arguments, etc).

If you find the `import` keyword disturbing for some unobvious reason, then you can also just declare the class by a FQN (Fully Qualified Name, thus including the full package name). E.g.:

```
@EJB
com.example.business.FooService fooService;
```

This way you can remove the `import com.example.business.FooService;` line.

#### See also:

- [Java Tutorial - Using Package Members](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)